# When should we use the integer types defined in stdint.h?

Tags: c, types

`stdint.h` defines integer types with specified width. When should we use those types, for example, `uint32_t` instead of `unsigned int`? Is it because we can obtain desired types without considering the underlying machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need to communicate with other systems and you want to be sure of the length of the data.

For example: you save your number to disk. How much long is it on disk? With an `unsigned int` the response is "it depends on the compiler, the OS...". With `uint32_t` it is 32 bits (4 bytes on "standard" architectures).

Comment: So if I know that using `unsigned int` won't cause any trouble then I can replace all `uint32_t` by `unsigned int`? I just read some source code, where the authors use both the `stdint.h` types and the built-in ones.

Comment: @PJ.Hades The problem is that the length of `unsigned int` isn't written in stone. For example during the passage of 32->64 bits some OS/compilers chose to make the `unsigned int` 64 bits long. The response is "it depends". I would need to see the code :-)

Comment: I see. The width of built-in types depend on the implementation of compilers and OS, but `stdint.h` types are guaranteed to be that long. Thanks :)

Comment: @BoBTFish `uint32_t` is 32 bit long, if that's 1 or 2 or 4 or 8 bytes doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: (Note I deleted a previous comment because I couldn't locate any proof). But see here: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/intrinsic-types.html#faq-26.4 In which case a 32 bit int wouldn't be possible. (ok this question is c not c++, but same principle applies).

Comment: @BoBTFish You are right, you should always measure in bits and not in bytes, because there are some more esoteric architectures where 1 byte is not 8 bits. And as a small note, `uint32_t` (and all the other similar types) are "optionale", so a compiler on those architectures could not provide them and refuse to compile.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I also found section 7.20.1.1: `The typedef name intN_t designates a signed integer type with width N, no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation. Thus, int8_t denotes such a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.`

Answer (score 3):

When the size and signedness of the integer is actually important.  Imagine you had a file or socket that delivers `uint32_t` values and you want to read it (in a portable way).  Reading just `unsigned int` values might be right, but may also horribly go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using `<stdint.h>` (or making your own surrogate) is very common in embedded development. It makes variable sizes and memory usage more obvious and porting a lot easier.
I find myself using `<stdint.h>` when writing desktop software in C now that I'm used to it from embedded development. Thinking of the size of the variables also force me to think of overflow cases etc.

To me it's just clean C to use `<stdint.h>`-defined types as it makes everything much more portable and the source code more explicit in its stack/heap allocation. Admitted, it makes more sense on memory constrained systems, but I still think it's good practice.